# How to polish porcelain?

Tags: repair, polish

Used a dremel to clean up a broken edge on a porcelain piece. The grinding wheel was pretty rough, what should I use to smooth it out? Also, any way to get it super smooth and polished like the rest of the item?

Comment: Use finer grinding wheels. But if it is through the surface layer then that is more of a challenge.

Comment: Whenever glass tile is polished on cut ends for backsplash work, the edges are polished with successive grits of 50G, 100G, 200G, 400G, 800G, 1500, and finally 3000G. 1500 get glass pretty shiny, 3000G really makes it more so You will need to use wet sanding to do this, heating up the porcelain will make it pop off the metal base. If it is porcelain dishes, it will crack the rest of the dish. That is if you use a machine to polish with, otherwise, you have a tremendous amount of hand work to do....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, porcelain isn't a polished smooth surface, it's a glazed sprayed on surface that's then fired at about 2300 degrees F. Once you've smoothed out the edge fill in any cracks or damaged areas with an epoxy glue. Let the glue self settle so it's a smooth surface and don't over apply. As far as matching the color, try nail polish. it comes in hundreds of colors and does a great job of sealing and self leveling for a smooth surface. I repaired a chip on a toilet and this really works well. Good luck